# Como usar una variable como array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código que me genera aleatoriamente una cadena alfanumérica:

```
var currentGameID = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
```

Luego, en el siguiente código, toma los nombres de los jugadores desde las cajas de texto y los almacena en un nuevo objeto, quedándome de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#newGame").click(function() {
            player1Name = $("#jugador1").val();
            player2Name = $("#jugador2").val();
            gamesSessions = {
                sessionID: {
                    gameID: {
                        player1Name: player1Name,
                        player2Name: player2Name
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    });
```

La salida queda de la siguiente manera: [image: salida]

Lo que necesito saber es de qué manera puedo hacer que la variable "currentGameID" sea el array que contenga a "player1Name" y "player2Name", así de esta manera podría guardar dentro de cada "currentGameID" los datos de los jugadores.

El código completo es el siguiente:

```
var currentGameID = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
    console.log(currentGameID);
    var player1Name;
    var player2Name;
    var gamesSessions;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#newGame").click(function() {
            player1Name = $("#jugador1").val();
            player2Name = $("#jugador2").val();
            gamesSessions = {
                sessionID: {
                    gameID: {
                        player1Name: player1Name,
                        player2Name: player2Name
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta.  Porque no haces esto: `currentGameId = gameSessions.sessionID.gameID;`

Comment: En pocas palabras lo que necesito es que cada "currentGameID" generado contenga los datos ingresados de los jugadores. De esta manera puedo identificar cada partida y, por ejemplo, resumirla. Sería algo así: gamesSessions -> sessionsID -> qzoz5th72mo -> player1Name: "Juan", player2Name: "Carlos"... y así con cada currentGameID generado.

Comment: No pude entender tu pregunta, la ley varias veces pero no pude dar con lo que quieres hacer, no se si puedas explicarte mejor  y escribir cual es el resultado que quieres tener ; además tu código no permite reproducir lo que estás haciendo porque gameID no está definida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te entiendo bien, lo que necesitas es que `currentGameID` sea un objeto y no un string.  Podrias hacerlo asi:

```js
        var currentGameID = {'id': Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)};
        
        var player1Name;
        var player2Name;
        var gamesSessions;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#newGame").click(function() {
                player1Name = $("#jugador1").val();
                player2Name = $("#jugador2").val();
                gamesSessions = {
                    "sessionID": {
                        "gameID": {
                            player1Name: player1Name,
                            player2Name: player2Name
                        }
                    }
                };
                currentGameID.jugadores = gamesSessions.sessionID.gameID;
                console.log(currentGameID);
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="jugador1"></input>
<input type="text" id="jugador2"></input>
<button id="newGame">Jugar</button>
```

Comment: Exactamente es eso lo que necesitaba! Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: De nada @matias y bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres guardar cada uno de los juegos en un array puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
var currentGameID=[];
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#newGame").click(function() {
            currentGameID.push({
                gameId:Math.random().toString(36).slice(2),
                gamesSessions:{
                    gameID: {
                        player1Name: $("#jugador1").val(),
                        player2Name: $("#jugador2").val()
                    }
                }
            });
            console.log(currentGameID);

    });
});
```

Puede que el código tenga errores  porque no lo he probado, pero lo que hace es usar la función push para agregar una posición nueva al array cada vez que se hace click en #newGame.

También puede que tengas que cambiar la estructura de tu objeto según tus necesidades y finalmente tienes que verificar que  la cadena generada por `Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)` no exista ya en otro juego